# Extension method and local 'this' variable

Tags: c#, extension-methods, local, ref

To my knowledge `this` in a extension method is passed as a `ref` variable. I can verify this by doing

```
public static void Method<T>(this List<T> list)
{
    list.Add(default(T));
}

List<int> ints = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
ints.Method();
```

My `List<int> ints` is now `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0`.

However when I do

```
public static void Method<T>(this List<T> list, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    list = list.Where(predicate).ToList();
}

List<int> ints = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
ints.Method(i => i > 2);
```

I would expect my `List<int> ints` to be `3, 4, 5` but remains untouched. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: `list` is not passed by reference, it is a reference passed by value. Passing by reference aliases the variable in the calling method inside the callee which allows you to assign to it directly.

Comment: There is a difference between "passing *by* reference" and "passing *a* reference". The reference to the list is passed by value, which means you can access and modify the list, but you're not touching the variable on the outside that is also referencing the list.

Comment: `(new List<int>()).Method()` compiles => argument need not be a variable at all => not like `ref`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `this` extension method parameter is passed by value, not by reference. What this means is that upon entering the extension method, you have two variables pointing to the same memory address: the original `ints` and the `list` parameter. When you add an item to the list inside the extension method, it is reflected in `ints`, because you modify an object referenced by both variables. When you reassign `list`, a new list is created on the managed heap and the extension method's parameter points to this list. The `ints` variable still points to the old list.

Answer (score 3):

Well, when you try to modify property of some class instance you don't even need `ref` because you're modifying instance rather then reference to it.

In this example you don't need `ref` keyword as you modify property :

```
    class MyClass
    {            
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    }

    static void Method(MyClass instance)
    {
        instance.MyProperty = 10;                     
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass instance = new MyClass();
        Method(instance);

        Console.WriteLine(instance.MyProperty);
    }
```

Output : 10

And here you do need `ref` keyword because you work with reference and not with instance :

```
    ...

    static void Method(MyClass instance)
    {
        // instance variable holds reference to same object but it is different variable
        instance = new MyClass() { MyProperty = 10 };
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass instance = new MyClass();
        Method(instance);

        Console.WriteLine(instance.MyProperty);
    }
```

Output: 0

It's same for your scenario, extension methods are the same as normal static methods and if you create new object inside method then either you use `ref` keyword (it's not possible for extension methods though) or return this object otherwise the reference to it will be lost.

So in your second case you should use :

```
public static List<T> Method<T>(this List<T> list, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    return list.Where(predicate).ToList();
}

List<int> ints = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
ints = ints.Method(i => i > 2);

foreach(int item in ints) Console.Write(item + " ");
```

Output : `3, 4, 5`